# Find next prime

Tags: python, performance

I am looking for a fast and memory efficient way to find the next prime.

**Input:** An integer `n`

**Output** The first prime bigger then `n`

There is really nice code to print all primes smaller than `n` at [Fastest way to list all primes below N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python/3035188) .  My inefficient method currently finds all primes smaller than `2n` and then searches for the first prime bigger than `n` by just looping through the list. Here is my current code.

```
import numpy
def primesfrom2to(n):
    """ Input n>=6, Returns a array of primes, 2 <= p < n """
    sieve = numpy.ones(n/3 + (n%6==2), dtype=numpy.bool)
    for i in xrange(1,int(n**0.5)/3+1):
        if sieve[i]:
            k=3*i+1|1
            sieve[       k*k/3     ::2*k] = False
            sieve[k*(k-2*(i&1)+4)/3::2*k] = False
    return numpy.r_[2,3,((3*numpy.nonzero(sieve)[0][1:]+1)|1)]

n=10**7
timeit next(x for x in primesfrom2to(2*n) if x > n)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.18 s per loop

n= 10**8
timeit next(x for x in primesfrom2to(2*n) if x > n)
1 loops, best of 3: 21.7 s per loop
```

This last test takes almost 1GB of RAM. Another problem with this code is that it just fails if $n = 10**10$ for example.

Can this problem be solved faster? Is there a way to get it to use less memory?

Comment: You could use miller-rabin (pseudo-)primality test.

Comment: A [very similar problem](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/10701/4098) was posted on the SE [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) subdomain. It might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do is apparently as follows.

1. Start a sieve at `n` until `2n` to eliminate numbers with small primes.
2. Run a probabilistic prime number tester such as Miller-Rabin on the remaining values.
3. If needed, run a deterministic prime tester on the first number that has been reported prime.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways of going around this. The first one I've tried recently - I made quite an efficient [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) in C++ and made it into a [C/C++ Extension for Python](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html).

It's memory efficient as it uses a bitmap instead of an actual array of `int`s and it's quite fast - for up to 10**9 it works for around 20s on a beat-up one core virtual machine (along with exporting the bitmap to actual ints). In your case you can keep only the bitmap and if you now the absolute max of `n` you can precompute the primes.

Another approach is to look into some [Primality tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test), but don't forget that some of them are probabilistic.

Comment: "don't forget that some of them are not deterministic."... So? You probably wanted to say they are *probabilistic*, meaning they give an answer which is correct within a certain probability range. There are a lot of non deterministic, yet perfectly correct algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely recommend some sort of sieve or filter.

While trying to solve a problem involving primes for funsies, I created the following in Python: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4960155

I am able to get through a couple million primes in about 15 seconds, IIRC. It was a little while back. I'm glad I saved it!